# Write a query to find the top 3 countries with highest suicides for each year from 1985-2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: I have already written a query to group by each country and suicide numbers with year.]

Pls see the image, i want to get the result as :

```
Year|First      |Second       |Third
1985|USA - 29446|Japan - 23257|France - 12501
1986|USA - 30892|Japan - 25484|France - 12529
and so on ..... till year 2016.
```

I know some function will be used to transform the data from row to column format. Just don't know how to do that in SQL Server. I know for Postgres it's CROSSTAB function.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: How far have you got? Have you been able to select the top 3 countries per year in rows? Is your only question how to get from rows to columns? Then look for the keywords "pivot" or "conditional aggregation". Please show your query.

Comment: Which countries would you show for 1987 if the numbers where USA 30000, Japan 20000, Germany 10000 and France 10000? Please edit your request to show how you want to deal with such edge cases where it is not exactly three top countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year
                                 ORDER BY total_suicides DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    year,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN country END) + ' - ' +
    CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1
                  THEN total_suicides END) AS varchar(10)) AS First,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN country END) + ' - ' +
    CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2
                  THEN total_suicides END) AS varchar(10)) AS Second,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN country END) + ' - ' +
    CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3
                  THEN total_suicides END) AS varchar(10)) AS Third
FROM cte
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year;
```

Comment: It is giving error "MAX" is not a recognized built - in function name.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo.  Please reload the page and try again.

Comment: Omg!! Thank you so much it works!! It is exactly what i wanted! Now i will analyze this and learn myself.